# Inbox count wrong a lot more often than it used to be

Tags: bug, global-inbox

In the past couple of weeks, I've found that my unread count (the red number) on my inbox is wrong (too high) most of the time if it's showing a number at all. This is new behavior.

Throughout the day, I'll regularly see it at `[2]` but click it and see that I only have one new notification; the other is one I've already cleared from the inbox previously. Or I'll see it at `[5]` and click to find there are really only two since I last cleared it.

Prior to a couple of weeks ago, this might happen *very* rarely, but now it's an every-day, more-than-once-a-day occurrence.

I'm primarily active on Stack Overflow.

Some change with unintended consequences?

Comment: Did you happen to visit chatrooms more often? Undismissed chat pings sometimes appear before the latest site ping as a notification, and sometimes confuse me as well.

Comment: @M.A.R.: Good question. I almost never go into chat rooms.

Comment: Events on same post (e.g. comments) are "joined" into one in the inbox itself, but think each event is raising the counter by 1.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: This is across posts.